# Getting the dimensions of the photo to be taken from expo-camera

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I was wondering if there was a way to configure the expo camera component size so that it was exactly as large as the picture being taken? I was also thinking that I could use the standard photo dimension information available for each platform, but I'm not exactly sure about how to go about doing that. If someone could point me to a bare flow solution, that would be helpful as well.